# Duplicate azure virtual machine

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-repos

I have been assigned with task to duplicate an instance azure virtual machine, for which I have found the solution.
The main purpose of creating duplicate is for testing, where any new changes will be pushed to duplicate virtual machine and after testing, if everything works, changes will be pushed to original virtual machine.

For this I have decided to follow article: [How to duplicate Azure Virtual Machine](https://gennaromigliaccio.com/how-to-duplicate-an-azure-virtual-machine)

- I want to know by creating duplicate of virtual machine will it affect original virtual machine from which duplicate is created?
- Pushing changes to duplicate virtual machine, will it have any affect on original virtual machine?
- Does azure charges for duplicate azure virtual machine as well?

I tried looking for answer but was unable to find on same. Please let me know if anyone needs any further information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to know by creating duplicate of virtual machine will it affect
> original virtual machine from which duplicate is created?

No. Since you will be creating a snapshot of your existing VM disk and using it to create a new VM, any changes applied to the new VM will not be reflected in the old VM (and vice versa).

> Pushing changes to duplicate virtual machine, will it have any affect
> on original virtual machine?

No. Same reason as above.

> Does azure charges for duplicate azure virtual machine as well?

Yes. Since your 2nd VM is a separate resource in your Azure Subscription, you will be charged for it. You could shut down the duplicate VM when not used and that would stop the billing for it.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking time and answering my queries. :)

Answer (score 0):

Duplicating VM's or pushing changes don't affect the original one, but both are considered as two different resources that you must pay for each of them.